# International Bitcoin Payment Platform

Tags: api, java, payment-processors

I need to integrate bitcoins payments in my web application.

I was about to use [Stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/guides/bitcoin) platform for accepting bitcoins (works exactly the same than for accepting credit cards) but I realized they need me to have a US bank account which I don't have.

Is there a similar service that offers an API (java preferrably) to easily accept bitcoin payments or do I have to write down the code myself?

(By the way, I'm new to bitcoin but have a good dev exp.)

Answer (score 0):

Answer is here, question already asked (sorry about that):

[How to integrate a Bitcoin payment service in my auction site](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/14447/how-to-integrate-a-bitcoin-payment-service-in-my-auction-site?rq=1)

my choice: https://bitpay.com/

Comment: Hi jon, welcome to the Bitcoin Stack Exchange! If you've found that there's another question that is essentially the same as yours, it's best to mark it as a duplicate like I did. Good luck getting bitcoin payments integrated into your website!